# Angular2 - How to change selected <select> element option on key press?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Following is my HTML:

```
<select id="movie" name="Movie"
  (keyup)="keyPress($event);"
  [(ngModel)]="movies.value.name"
  <option *ngFor="let movie of movieNameOptions" [value]="movie.value">{{ movie.label }}
  </option>
</select>
```

I am populating the options from the model.

I need to scroll through movie options inside  tag programmatically on a particular F9 key press.

This is what my f9 keyPress function looks like:

```
keyPress(event): void {
        if(event.keyCode === 120) {
           // not sure what to do here
        }
}
```

How do I go about scrolling through available option by pressing F9?
For example, if I have five items and I am on the item #3, by pressing F9, selected option should switch to item #4.  Another press, it should go to item #5. Another press it should land on item #1 again.

Comment: Get the index of the currently selected movie (i.e. the one whose value is equal to movies.value.name), then set movies.value.name to the value of the next movie in the array. But why not use the standard keyboard shortcuts, directly supported by the browser, instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The principle of the solution is demonstrated by Kind user's answer. The code could be simpler, though:

```
  <select id="movie" name="Movie"
          (keyup.f9)="f9Pressed()"
          [(ngModel)]="movies.value.name">
    <option *ngFor="let movie of movieNameOptions" [value]="movie.value">
      {{ movie.label }}
    </option>
  </select>
```

and

```
f9Pressed() {
  let index = this.movieNameOptions.map(m => m.value).indexOf(this.movies.value.name);
  index = (index + 1) % this.movieNameOptions.length;
  this.movies.value.name = this.movieNameOptions[index].value;
}
```

See http://plnkr.co/edit/Bbf7Yh7NEqun6DKsFwQm?p=preview for a complete plunkr.

Comment: It's less of code here, but - to be honest - it's kinda more complicated. But anyways, that's a really clever code.

Comment: Thank you both, you've really helped a lot. Much appreciated. @Kinduser, if you don't mind I'll mark this answer as a solution.

Comment: @JB Nizet this guy!! MVP

Answer (score 3):

Took a while but I've made something for you.

If you click **`F9`** button, the selected value will be incremented by one. When it reaches the last element of the `moviesList` array, the selected value gets reseted to the first one.

**`app.component.html`**

```
<select id="movie" name="Movie" (keyup)="keyPress($event)" 
  [(ngModel)]="selectedMovie" autofocus>
<option *ngFor="let movie of moviesList">{{ movie.movie }}</option>
```

**`app.component.ts`**

```
  selectedMovie: string;
  moviesList = [{movie: 'Shrek'}, {movie: 'Inception'}, {movie: 'Interstellar'},  {movie: 'Star Wars'},  {movie: 'Nemo'} , {movie: 'Pluton'},  {movie: 'Pokemon'}];
  i: number = 0;

  constructor() { 
    this.selectedMovie = this.moviesList[0].movie;
  }

  keyPress(event): void {
     this.i = this.moviesList.map(v => v.movie == this.selectedMovie).indexOf(true);
        if (event.keyCode === 120) {
          this.i++;
          if (this.i < this.moviesList.length) {
            this.selectedMovie = this.moviesList[this.i].movie;
          } else {
            this.selectedMovie = this.moviesList[0].movie;
            this.i = 0;
          }    
      } 
  }
```

**[Plunker link](https://plnkr.co/edit/i5hii6N9PelIYSWs5vwg?p=preview)**

Comment: It would be great if the question would contain the essential parts directly instead of only in a link to an external resource.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Done, mate.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that if you select an option without pressing F9 (using the mouse for example), the next option selected by F9 is not the option following the selected one anymore. Instead of using `i`, the function should find the index of the selected option.

Comment: @JBNizet just find the value bind to the ngModel in the array and get the index, then +1/-1 just check indexOutOfBounds.

Comment: See http://plnkr.co/edit/Bbf7Yh7NEqun6DKsFwQm?p=preview for a simpler solution that doesn't have this problem

Comment: @JBNizet that's, you should post the code as the answer, gj!

Comment: This answer is "good enough" to me, because it shows the principle of the solution.

Comment: @JBNizet I've posted a working solution. Thanks mate for pointing it out. Have a great day!

Comment: @JBNizet, post this as a solution. That's awesome, thanks a lot.